# Using tensorflow_dataset library on AI Platform (CMLE)

Tags: python, tensorflow, generative-adversarial-network, gcp-ai-platform-training

I am using tesorflow_datasets library for mnist dataset to train on GCP AI Platform. I am using tf.gan estimator. I have written an input pipeline which reads mnist data using tfds library.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split=self.split, shuffle_files=self.shuffle)
```

I have trained my gan model using the same 'tensorflow_datasets' library on the instance and model is training fine. I have wrapped my code into package to run it on AI Platform. During training on AI Platform, the training is stuck with a warning, it shows,

```
Dataset mnist is hosted on GCS. It will automatically be downloaded to your local data
directory. If you'd instead prefer to read directly from our public GCS bucket.
```

Although the training is stuck, ML units consumed keep on increasing.

Answer (score 1):

The 'tensorflow_datasets' library takes an argument 'data_dir'. If you are using this library on GCP, It is recommended to use 'data_dir' which takes bucket bath where tensorflow datasets have been uploaded.

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds = tfds.load('mnist', split=self.split,shuffle_files=self.shuffle, \
     data_dir='gs://tfds-data/datasets')
```

Hope this will. You can also check this bucket. Its a public bucket which contains datasets.

```
gsutil ls gs://tfds-data/datasets/
```

You can see all datasets

```
gs://tfds-data/datasets/
gs://tfds-data/datasets/downloads/
gs://tfds-data/datasets/groove/
gs://tfds-data/datasets/mnist/
gs://tfds-data/datasets/nsynth/
gs://tfds-data/datasets/wikipedia/
```